# Verifying reasoning for vector span.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Letting u and v span R2, I'm trying to prove that if span{v} = span{u}, it doesn't have to mean u = v. I took 2 vectors, letting v1 = [1 2] and u1 = [5 10]. These 2 vectors are not equal, but they are in the same span because there is a common scalar value. Is this reasoning correct? I'm just trying to get these concepts understood.

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: "*Letting $u$ and $v$ span R2*"  I am not fully sure I understand what you mean by this sentence.  Usually when I hear this it means that $\text{span}(u,v)=\Bbb R^2$ but if that were true it would be impossible for $\text{span}(u)=\text{span}(v)$.  Surely, for your first sentence you mean to say that merely $u,v\in\Bbb R^2$ instead of saying that they span it.

Comment: @JMoravitz Yes that is what i mean. I should have written it correctly.